# Can I queue up and run a set number of tasks in windows shell?

Tags: command-prompt

I have a dozen large processing tasks I need to run, each one contained in its own .bat file. I want to run them concurrently, but I cannot run all of them at once since they each take about 500MB RAM to finish.

Is there a better way than to just "start" the first 4 or so, and check for the text files to show up then "start" the next process... repeat?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect, but you could use `START "title" /B filename.exe`

For example:

```
START "task1" /B 1.exe
START "task2" /B 2.exe
START "task3" /B 3.exe
START "task4" /B /WAIT 4.exe

START "task5" /B 5.exe
START "task6" /B 6.exe
START "task7" /B 7.exe
START "task8" /B /WAIT 8.exe
```

Where the wait on the last command of each group will make it wait for the first batch to finish before starting the second batch.  The flaw here is that it won't start each new task as one of the others finishes, it will only start them in groups.

Comment: I think this will do the trick since I can estimate the completion time of the tasks and just group them intelligently. 

Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Yes, if you make the tasks that are waited for the shorter ones, then it should be able to start up more tasks before the entire last group finishes, so you aren't wasting cycles.

Comment: Is there a way to make this log to a file? My command prompt seems to disappear when something goes wrong with no log.